# Spring boot syntax on run()

Tags: spring-boot

Why is Spring Framework asking the developer to explicitly write the class name from where it is being called like

```
SpringApplication.run(ClassA.class, args);
```

It would be a lot easier and cleaner for the Spec guys as well as compiler to have a syntax like

```
SpringApplication.run(args);
```

where the class is implicitly the current class.

The whole idea of encapsulation is hiding internal details. So why can't we have Spring Boot framework encapsulate the current class argument automatically. Most of the syntax that were there in Java 1.2 are completely lost or modified or shortened as syntactic sugar in 1.8. Don't you think it is high time we update Spring Boot syntax?

Comment: There's actually a `run` method [without the primary source argument](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0ad72d5b5e2d9ccef09d4639002da4ad712a7f5d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L295), however I think it doesn't do the same job that you state in the question. Still, I guess this argument is used to provide the ability for the primary source argument to be different than the current class.

Comment: Makes sense to have an overloaded method that can take the additional class parameter, but that seems to a valid candidate only for a exception rather than a generalization scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory to create the `main` method inside the `@SpringBootApplication` class. So by providing the class argument in the `SpringApplication.run` method one can specify the class that should be loaded.

For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringApplication {
    //no main method here
}
```

And

```
public class AppStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MySpringApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks pleft. In your example, what methods of MySpringApplication class will be run when SpringBoot hits Appstarter.main()? How does the SB framework decide the next set of action from a class that does not have a main()?

Comment: Can't say that I understood your question. Care to rephrase it or elaborate more? What do you mean by saying "what methods of MySpringApplication". In my example this class has no other methods. Of course you can add `@Bean` methods to create beans and they should work as expected. `MySpringApplication` is annotated as `@SpringBootApplication` so `SpringBoot` knows what it has to do.

Answer (score 1):

How would `SpringApplication.run(args);` refer to "current" class altogether? It is a static method, so it cannot just call `getClass()` and use this as an implicit argument.

What it could do is to *guess* from where it is being called for example by obtaining the current stack trace

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

and iterating stack trace elements until it finds some `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. To me this however seems a bit fragile as this is not very intuitive and easy to break with refactorings. Besides as others already noted, the class invoking `SpringApplication.run(args);` by no means has to be the actual spring application.

Comment: I think I have put it plain and simple. If you still don't get the drift, let me elaborate even more. The whole idea of encapsulation is hiding internal details. So why can't we have Spring Boot framework encapsulate the current class argument automatically. Most of the syntax that were there in Java 1.2 are completely lost or modified or shortened as syntactic sugar in 1.8. Why ? Because it is easier for developers right.!! I rest my case!.